# How do I use the spell Affinity?

Tags: controllers, dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

In Dark Souls 2/Scholar of the First Sin, how do I use the spell Affinity with an Xbox 360 controller? I can cast the spell, but how do I launch the projectiles?

Comment: Make sure to check the controls setting in game

Comment: @Will309 It is not defined in the controls menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Affinity works much in the same way as Pursuers did in Dark Souls 1. Once cast, when an enemy gets within a certain range, they will automatically fire at the enemy.

From the [wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Affinity):

> Similar to Pursuers from DkS1. Cast a number of orbs that deal dark damage. The orbs **target and home to the closest enemy**.

The controller has nothing to do with it :)

Comment: I didn't know if it was an automatic thing or I had to press a button.